# How do I grant another Github user access only to my repo traffic graphs?

Tags: git, github, analytics

Github recently introduced [Traffic Analytics](https://github.com/blog/1672-introducing-github-traffic-analytics) and looks like the charts can only be seen by seen by repo owner and collaborators. Now I have a personal account (not an organization) and I need to grant another user access to those charts. I could add him as a collaborator, but this would also allow him to make changes which isn't really needed.

How do I grant another user access only to my repo traffic data?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can’t.

GitHub introduced that feature explicitely for repository owners and collaborators, as clear by their description: (emphasis mine)

> You can now see detailed analytics data for repositories that **you're an owner of** or that **you can push to**.

So unless either of that condition is true, that other person won’t be able to see the data.

It also doesn’t seem to be supported by the API (yet) so you won’t be able to provide him with the data in another way (other than maybe screenshotting it).

So, if you really want that other user to see the data, you will have to add him as a collaborator. You could of course just ask him, not to push anything.

Comment: Can I achieve what I want by using an organization account?

Comment: No, the same rules apply there; you can only see the traffic graphs for repositories when you have push rights to it (I just checked that).